# Is there any way to replace a SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` query?

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to replace the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` LIKE '{$this>arrConfig['dbDatabase']}' 
AND `TABLE_NAME` LIKE '%$strTable'
```

by a query starting by

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM ...
```

I have to do this because my host doesn't accept select queries on INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to use `LIKE`, because you don't have the exact name of the database and table?

Comment: SHOW COLUMNS FROM schema.tablename.  You might want to set up all of that as a var or string and then execute the var/string.

Comment: @barmar : I have the exact name of the Database but not the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%$strTable'
```

to get all the table names, then for each of them you can do:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tableName
```